# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tfrac{n}{1}+\tfrac{n-1}{2}+\dots+\tfrac{2}{n-1}+\tfrac{1}{n}}{\ln(n!)}$

Tags: limits

How can I compute the following limit?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{n}{1}+\dfrac{n-1}{2}+\dots+\dfrac{2}{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{n}}{\ln(n!)}
$$

I have tried lots of methods, I can't get the answer.
Although I think the limit is $0$, I don't know how to explain it. Please, if someone could help me it would be fantastic.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you tried and upload it to us? We like to see what your efforts have been so that we can better help you with this problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i%3D1+to+n+of+(n-i%2B1)%2Fi) says the sum on the top is $(n+1)H_n-n$. $H_n\approx \ln n$ for big n, so this gives us $n\ln n+\ln n-n$ over $\ln(n!)$. $\ln(n!)$ is about $n\ln n$, so I'm guessing the limit is $1$. However, this is very rough reasoning, so don't trust me on that.

Comment: OK, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+n+approaches+infinity+of+((n%2B1)*H_n-n)%2Fln(n!)) confirms the limit is $1$.

Comment: Hint: Use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 5):

Let $H_n:= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$.

$\ln(n!)\sim n(\ln(n)-1)$ by Stirling's formula.

As for the numerator, it is $nH_n-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3}-\cdots-\frac{n-1}{n}= nH_n-(n-1)+H_n-1$.

There are very strong estimations for $H_n$, for example $H_n= \ln(n)+\gamma+O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Putting all this together yields that the limit is $1$, you can even obtain a nice error term that the sequence is in fact $1+O(\frac{1}{\ln(n)})$.

Comment: Thank you fo helping!!!

Comment: I am glad I could help. If you think this answers your question, you should accept the answer.