# Calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\frac{n}{1} + \frac{n-1}{2} + \frac{n-2}{3} + ... + \frac{2}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}}{\ln(n!)}}$

Tags: limits

I have tried to use the Stolz theorem and calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}}$ and i have reached $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n-2} + \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}}{\ln (n+1)}}$ but I do not know how to continue. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this problem from? It has been asked a couple of days ago: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055274/compute-lim-n-to-infty-frac-tfracn1-tfracn-12-dots-tfrac2n-1/3055315#3055315

Answer (score 1):

Hint: See the "Rate of divergence" section of [the Wikipedia article about the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), or the definition of the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: So i can rewrite the top part as $\ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}$?

Comment: No....but you can *approximate* it by that (or better still, find upper and lower bounds and use the squeeze lemma).

Comment: Ok thanks I will try